# How to properly implement load balancer healthcheck for Grails

Tags: grails, load-balancing

I'm working with a Grails 2 application that is deployed to Amazon AWS which uses a software load balancer (ELB).  The problem we are having is that the grails application instances are added to the load balancer before the application is fully initialized. It's the `resources` plugin specifically which serves static assets like javascript, css, images, etc.

The load balancer makes an http request to a 'healthcheck' URL.

`GET '/myapp/lbcheck'`

LoadBalancerController.groovy:

```
package myapp

class LoadBalancerController {

    def healthService

    def healthcheck() {
        response.contentType = 'text/plain'
        try {
            healthService.checkDatabase()
            render(status: 200, text: "Up")
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error with database healthcheck " + ex)
            render(status: 503, text: "Down")
        }
    }
}
```

HealthSerivce.groovy

```
package myapp

import groovy.sql.Sql

class HealthService {

    def dataSource

    // Either returns true, or throws an Exception
    def checkDatabase() {
        Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        sql.rows("SELECT 429")
        sql.close()
        return true
    }
}
```

The SQL query clearly isn't enough.  It seems like we need to check some other kind of property in the framework to determine that it has been initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting setting a field on your `healthService` bean to true inside of `BootStrap.groovy`. I think that's run after Grails is fully initialized.

```
package myapp

import groovy.sql.Sql

class HealthService {

    def dataSource

    def initializationComplete = false

    // Either returns true, or throws an Exception
    def checkDatabase() {
        Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        sql.rows("SELECT 429")
        sql.close()
        return true
    }
}
```

inside `BootStrap.groovy`:

```
class BootStrap {
    def healthService

    def init = { servletContext ->
        healthService.initializationComplete = true
    }

}
```

in your `LoadBalancerController.groovy`:

```
def healthcheck() {
    response.contentType = 'text/plain'
    def healthy = false
    try {
        healthy = healthService.with { 
            initializationComplete && checkDatabase()
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        log.error("Error with database healthcheck " + ex)
    }

    if (healthy) {
        render(status: 200, text: "Up")
    } else {
        render(status: 503, text: "Down")
    }
}
```